# PostgreSQL: Unexpected array element

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

Writing a Node application that's pushing some data to a Postgres DB. One column's data type is an Array of a custom Composite type.

Here's what I'm trying to inject:

```
'{(123, (12, "Some Description")),(null, (34, "Some Desc"))}'
```

The composite type has two fields, the 2nd of which is another composite type. The error I'm getting back from Postgres is gives me the message:

> malformed array literal: "{(123, (12, "Some Description")),(null, (34, "Some Desc"))}"

With the detail:

> Unexpected array element

The column is declared as data type:

```
my_custom_data_type[]
```

Can't figure this exception out.

Comment: Have you tried `array[(123, (12, "Some Description")),(null, (34, "Some Desc"))]` or `array[(123, (12, "Some Description")),(null, (34, "Some Desc"))]::my_custom_data_type[]`? The array constructor syntax (`array[...]`) is often easier to work with than the string form (`'{...}'`).

Comment: @muistooshort That worked perfectly, heroic suggestion. If you want to submit it as an answer I'll mark it as correct. Have to imagine someone else will run into this at some point. With composite data types, it seems, you have to use the `::my_custom_data_type[]` approach you mentioned to use them in an array. Also -- thanks a million

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string version of arrays (`'{...}'`) can be cumbersome to work with, especially with more complex array entries like you have. I tend to prefer the [array constructor syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) so that everything is a plain old value:

```
array[(123, (12, 'Some Description')), (null, (34, 'Some Desc'))]::my_custom_data_type[]
```

This array syntax also tends to work better with ORMs and the like.

The `::my_custom_data_type[]` type cast helps make sure the parser knows what you're trying to say, you should be able to get away with just casting the first entry:

```
array[(123, (12, 'Some Description'))::my_custom_data_type, (null, (34, 'Some Desc'))]
```

but it is probably cleaner and easier to cast the whole array.